# How to select check in and check out date using selenium in goibibo/hotels.com (Area Mumbai)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

#How to select check in and check out date using selenium in goibibo/hotels.com (Area Mumbai)#
Suppose I want to select check in date 25 august 2021 and checkout date 3 September 2021
[image: Goibibo Date Selection Image]

https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/

```
package com.bean;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Goibibo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_2\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     //Goto Url Goibibo.com
     driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/");
     System.out.println("WWW.GOIBIBO.COM");
     
     //Select Country India
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CountryType']")).click();

     System.out.println("Selected Country India");
     // Click on Search Bar
     driver.findElement(By.id("downshift-1-input")).click();

     System.out.println("Clicked On Search Bar");

     //Select Mumbai City
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Mumbai']"))).click();
     System.out.println("Print Mumbai !");
     
     driver.findElement(By.id("search-widget-checkin-input")).click();
     System.out.println("Select Check In");
     
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is YOUR code? What have YOU tried? What errors faced?

Comment: Which date you wanna select ? is there any code you have tried ? any error stack trace ?

Comment: Yes I have tried, suppose I want to select 21 August 2021 . I will add code

Answer (score 0):

Some of your xpath seems wrong

```
 //Select Country India
 //This returns both radio buttons
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CountryType']")).click();
```

make it like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='India']")).click();
```

rest of the code seems to be working for opening check-in date-picker

After that, you can select check-in and check-out date like this:

For selecting 25th date in left date picker

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, "dcalendar-newstyles__DayAndDateLeftWrapper")]//ul[contains(@class, "dcalendar-newstyles__DateWrapDiv")]//*[text()='25']")).click();
```

For selecting 3th date in right date picker

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, "dcalendar-newstyles__DayAndDateRightWrapper")]//ul[contains(@class, "dcalendar-newstyles__DateWrapDiv")]//*[text()='3']")).click();
```

I know that those xpaths are very bad. But since the website you are provided are included locators with too much random letters and numbers and I didn't see any unique locator like id. So I couldn't find any better way.

Comment: actually xpath is very bad (: ,not working

Comment: I've tried those xpaths with chropath extension and they were working. Do you get error or it does just do nothing? Maybe adding short Thread.sleep after opened date picker, would help.

Comment: at dcalendar, Syntax error on token "dcalendar", delete this token error occur and at /ul[contains(@class,   Syntax error on token "")]//ul[contains(@class, "", -> expected error occurd